# Delete <li> tag of "Forgot Password", "Registration"

Tags: php, joomla-2.5, login

I have a little problem on one of my Joomla website.
I had to delete the `Forgot Password`... the 2/3 Links that appears under the login module. They're gone now, but still there is 3 `<li>` section, so 3 little dots I can't remove. How can I change that ?

The bug :
[image]

Thanks

Comment: How did you delete them?

Comment: I deleted the line 56 to end in `default_login.php`(components/com_users/views/login/tmpl/)

Comment: Login module or login component? Is it a part of a page or a whole login page?

Comment: It's a component . Yeah sorry for the mistake ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than delete this functionality, the best thing to do would be to disable it.

To do this, in your backend go to:

http://YOURSITE.com/index.php?option=com_config&view=component&component=com_users

In the first option which appears, set "Allow User Registration" to No

Once you've done this, you need to create an override in your Joomla template. Simply go to the backend of your site (via FTP) and browse to:

modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php and copy (be sure not to move it) this file into:

/templates/YOURTEMPLATE/html/mod_login/default.php (If mod_login isn't a folder, just create it).

Once you have got the file in there, open it in your favourite editor and remove the following:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=reset'); ?>">
        <?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_FORGOT_YOUR_PASSWORD'); ?></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=remind'); ?>">
        <?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_FORGOT_YOUR_USERNAME'); ?></a>
    </li>
    <?php
    $usersConfig = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_users');
    if ($usersConfig->get('allowUserRegistration')) : ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=registration'); ?>">
            <?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_REGISTER'); ?></a>
    </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

The above is roughly lines 60 -> 77

That should then revolve it!

### Update

If you want to override the user login component, you need to copy the file from

```
/components/com_users/views/login/tmpl/default_login.php
```

to

```
/templates/YOURTEMPLATE/html/com_users/login/default_login.php
```

and remove this part from the copied file:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=reset'); ?>">
            <?php echo JText::_('COM_USERS_LOGIN_RESET'); ?></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=remind'); ?>">
            <?php echo JText::_('COM_USERS_LOGIN_REMIND'); ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php
        $usersConfig = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_users');
        if ($usersConfig->get('allowUserRegistration')) : ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=registration'); ?>">
                <?php echo JText::_('COM_USERS_LOGIN_REGISTER'); ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

About line 57 ~ 76.

Comment: I got a 404 with this ..

Comment: With what? The above URL? You need to replace the YOURSITE.com with yoursite URL

Comment: Just try to modify the file, but it doesn't work the dots are still there

Comment: Check your spelling of mod_login folder within the /html/ folder of your template and the default.php file This could possibly be causing the issue.

Comment: mod_login and default.php
Do you see any mistake I cannot see ?

Comment: Once the folder/file is within the /html/ folder of your template it should override the core files.

Comment: Yeah It does, the link are not there, but the dots are still here !

Comment: But it's like they're invisible, because they're still visible in html code source

Comment: Have you cleared the Joomla cache and your browser cache?

Comment: Yes, more than once, I force quit Chrome, Safari, Firefox, I reboot my mac .. nothing works

Comment: @fari has kindly updated the above code with a solution for the component override

Answer (score 2):

First of all, *don't change any of the Joomla core files*, your changes will be lost when you update Joomla.

To remove the `User Registration` option, go to **Users** -> **User Manager** in your Joomla admin area, and click <kbd>Options</kbd> in the upper right corner. Then set `Allow User registration` to **No**. This will completely disable the user registration option. (You can still create new users from the Joomla backend).

[image: Joomla User Manager]

As for removing `Forgot your username` and `Forgot your password`, I would simply use CSS to hide it.

In your template's `custom.css` file (or similar), add the following code to hide the links in question:

```
.login + div {
   display: none;
}
```

**Note:**
The login component seems to render these links in `<div>` and `<li>` tags *without* any class or ID, thus making it impossible to target them directly using CSS. The above code will target any `<div>` tag that shows up **immediately after** the `<div class="login ">` block, thus hiding the links.

Keep in mind that even if the links are hidden, the functions can be accessed by using a direct URL.

*Forgot your password?*
http://example.com/index.php?option=com_users&view=reset

*Forgot your username?*
http://example.com/index.php?option=com_users&view=remind